# How to load an object file in three.js?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm trying to load a .obj file in three.js but I'm having trouble importing the libraries for the object loader. In the console it says THREE.OBJLoader2 is not a constructor. I'm trying to load the file locally.

I also tried loading the .gltf file using the gltfloader library, but I can't seem to import the libraries correctly.

this is the html code to import the OBJLoader script:

```
<script src="resources/threejs/r105/js/loaders/LoaderSupport.js"></script>
<script src="resources/threejs/r105/js/loaders/OBJLoader2.js"></script>
```

this is the js code for obj loader:

```
    const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader2();
    objLoader.load('house.obj', (event) => {
    const root = event.detail.loaderRootNode;
    scene.add(root);
});
```

I also tried to import the libraries locally by creating a GLTFLoader.js file and using

```
  <script src="GLTFLoader.js"></script>
```

but that did not work either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should use OBJLoader without the 2 as it seems dead. You can also try just removing the `2` without changing the path

Comment: As mentioned above you really should not use `OBJLoader2`. I suggest you use the latest version `r139` (and not `r105`) and the load your OBJ asset via `OBJLoader` according to the following example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj

Comment: Sidenote: I'm not sure why you mentioned `GLTFLoader`. Just to clarify this loader can't load OBJ assets.